# jquery autocomplete set hidden input value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have the following jquery autocomplete which does work.

```
<input type="hidden" id="autocompletePid" autocomplete="off" />
```

The relevant JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete(
                {
                    source : function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type : 'GET',
                            url : "/live-search" + '?term=' + request.term,
                            success : function(data) {
                                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                    return {
                                        label : item.street + ' '
                                                + item.city.city + ', '
                                                + item.state.stateCode
                                                + ' '
                                                + item.zipcode.zipcode,
                                        value : item.pid
                                    }
                                }));
                            },
                            minLength : 3
                        })
                    }

                });

    });
</script>
```

The relevant HTML

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-hide">
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete" autocomplete="off"
        placeholder="Enter an address or city..." /> <input
        type="submit" value="GO" />
</div>
```

The issue I'm facing is that with the current code, the value gets changed to `pid` which would make no sense to the user. I added a hidden input and I want to change the value of the hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" id="autocompletePid" autocomplete="off" />
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            //Create a array call 'auto_array'
            var auto_array = {};
            var label = '';
            $("#autocomplete").autocomplete(
                    {
                        source : function(request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type : 'GET',
                                url : "/live-search" + '?term=' + request.term,
                                success : function(data) {
                                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                    label  = item.street + ' '+ item.city.city  + ', '+ item.state.stateCode + ' '+ item.zipcode.zipcode;

                                    //Put the id of label in to auto_array. use the label as key in array
                                    auto_array[label] = item.pid;
                                    return label;

                                    }));
                                },

                            })
                        },

                       minLength : 3,

                        //On select the label get the value(id) from auto_array and put in hidden input field 'autocompletePid'
                         select: function(event, ui) {
                         console.log(auto_array);
                         $('#autocompletePid').val(auto_array[ui.item.value]);
                        }

                    });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This works well, but even though I have `minLength : 10` autocomplete starts as soon as I type a single character. Any idea why?

Comment: keep the ' minLength : 3' outside the sources. autocomplete will start after type 3 char. I edited the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Change your return value to save the pid. set label and value to be your displayed value:

   ```
   var label = item.street + ' '
               + item.city.city + ', '
               + item.state.stateCode
               + ' '
               + item.zipcode.zipcode;
   return {
       label : label,
       value : label,
       pid : item.pid
   }
   ```
2. Bind to `select` function from autocomplete to set the value to a different field as you desired

   ```
   select: function (event, ui) {
       $(autocompletePid).val(ui.item ? ui.item.pid : "");
   }
   ```

Here's the full working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9zyejd0/16/. Notes:

1. I changed the hidden input to a disabled text, so you can see the value changes.
2. I used mocky.io to simulate an API call. It ignores the typed value, just returns a constant address as you defined in your code.
3. Please note that `select` won't trigger when you delete a value from your text box. You should either manually bind to `change` (which will make the hidden field be updated when you focus out of the text field, a little uglier, but works better), or manually fix it with `$(autocomplete).focusout`.